# Android- Animation within Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to animate some Buttons in a Fragment but I keep getting the FATAL EXCEPTION: main error.
I'm using the AnimationUtils class to load animations.

Here's my Fragment's code::

```
public class StartFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);
        Button button1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_in);
        button1.startAnimation(slideIn);
        button2.startAnimation(slideIn);
        return rootView;
    }  
}
```

I also tried running the animation from the Activity that host this fragment but that didnt work either.

Is it even possible to run animations in a fragment?

EDIT:

slide_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

Logcat :

```
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lostbeatlive/com.lostbeatlive.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2281)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5124)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at com.lostbeatlive.StartFragment.onCreateView(StartFragment.java:21)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5217)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2204)
12-03 21:41:05.843: E/AndroidRuntime(9841):     ... 11 more

Comment: Please also post your logcat with the full stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error that you get? Please post the logcat, and the xml that defines animation please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fragment, you use CreateView to set things up. The view created is where you get the findViewById.  Instead of:

```
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);
    Button button1 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Try this:

```
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);
    Button button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Comment: Fragment's onViewCreated could also be used http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Does this go into the fragment.java or the Activity.java file??

Comment: onCreate is for Activities.  onCreateView is for fragments.  Put the above block of code into your fragment's onCreateView method